# fatal: empty ident name (for <webapp@ip-172-31-28-185.us-east-2.compute.internal>) not allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have A ruby app in aws which will create new repo in github, it works fine with heroku. But in aws the log says,

```
Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <webapp@ip-172-31-28-185.us-east-2.compute.internal>) not allowed
```

[Puma.log](https://pastebin.com/0gxu89r1)
[eb.activity.log](https://pastebin.com/w63YER55)
Why it is saying "/home/webapp: No such file or directory"

"git_initializer.rb"

```
system("echo intializing git")
`git config --global user.name soumjo&& git config --global user.email soumjo@gmail.com`
`cd && touch .netrc`
`chmod 600 .netrc`
File.write(".netrc",
    <<-HEREDOC
machine github.com
login soumjo
password #{ENV['github_pwd']}
HEREDOC
    )
```

Comment: Do I need to add a procfile?

Comment: need write access to "home/webapp"